# Second REST call within InfoPath causes state service error

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-services, infopath-data-connections

I have an infopath form, which uses both SOAP and REST web services. When I work inside InfoPath form preview, everything works well. The problem is when I publish the form and use it from the IE browser, even though I am referencing the exact same web services.

What happens in detail is the following.

1. On form load, I query REST service that I have created and it populates a repeating table. At this point, it works perfectly and the form opens.
2. When I try to execute that same REST service any time after form is opened, I get "A Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service error occurred while processing your request. For more information, contact your server farm administrator."
   In the logs, I only get "StateManager.GetState() Locked data" as the exception.

The server where the REST is referring to is the same as where the sharepoint/infopath resides.

SOAPs submit work fine at all times.

Anyone else had similar scenario?

Thanks,
Branko

UPDATE TO THE QUESTION:
Looking at the google chrome developer's tools, I find an error "Pagerequestmanager Cannot Be Initialized More Than Once" when I try to run the REST call the second time, the time of the error described above. It looks like it might be a postback issue, but no clue how to solve it in infopath with no code.

Comment: Have your tried Starting 'Service Bus Message Broker' and 'service bus gateway' from your WFM Server.

Comment: They are running but still nothing. I don't understand what the issue is - do you have a better idea what it might be?

Comment: Check database space for 'StateService'

Comment: Not that either.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with permission for the user account you are trying open the info path form. Or you may try giving contribute rights to all user on site collection level and try if the form is opening.

[For Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e4d855f7-50e6-4b4f-b226-fc1efe4d4099/state-service-error-when-submitting-infopath-form-to-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Permissions are not the issue. The form is loaded initially with the REST call as expected. If I execute the same call again after form has loaded then I get the error message.
Looking at the chrome debugger, I get "The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once" when I try to run that second REST call.